# How to get the current directory?

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I want to access the current directory like below `"E:WindowsFormsApplication17`

but i am getting the directory as like below `"E:\\BugBursters\\BuildUtility\\WindowsFormsApplication17\\bin\\Debug"`

I have used the below code `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks and Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: `"E:WindowsFormsApplication17` is not a valid path; `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will gives you the current working directory

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is returning you the path where the executable is being run.     What exactly are you trying to achieve?   Why do you need the path to your project source code?    Your project source normally wouldn't be deployed with your application, and therefore wouldn't exist at runtime.

Comment: If you want the directory the executable has started from, you can get it via `Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])`. Please, notice that the *current directory* can be changed.

Comment: I want to get this path "E:\\BugBursters\\BuildUtility\\WindowsFormsApplication17"

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

For get your path :

```
string sourcePath =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```